# models.BooleanField(default=False) returning True instead of false

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

```
issevenDisabled=models.BooleanField(default=False)
issevenSaved=models.BooleanField(default=False)
iseightDisabled=models.BooleanField(default=False)
iseightSaved=models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

output:
"issevenDisabled": true,
"issevenSaved": true,
"iseightDisabled": true,
"iseightSaved": true,

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the data you are saving, and ensure you are not explicitly setting the values to `True` when creating the object.
2. Check any model overriding method like `save()`.
3. This is a long short but check if your migrations were applied.

ps: It might be appropriate to use choices instead